# How to hide the markers default of GMapControl, Code by C#?

Tags: c#, google-maps, gmap.net

As my title, Please help to hide the markers default of GMapControl. I use the language C#. Please see the red box in picture below.
Thank you so much.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVbyl.png)

This is my code. Please see below. Thank you so much :)

```
gmap.MapProvider = GMapProviders.GoogleMap;
gmap.DragButton = MouseButtons.Left;
gmap.ShowCenter = false;
gmap.MinZoom = 1;
gmap.MaxZoom = 100;
gmap.Zoom = 10;
gmap.Manager.Mode = AccessMode.ServerAndCache;

GMapOverlay markers = new GMapOverlay("markers");

Brush ToolTipBackColor = new SolidBrush(Color.Transparent);
Brush foreground = Brushes.Green;

for (int i = 0; i < points.Count; i++)
{
    GMapMarker marker = new GMarkerGoogle(points[i], 
    GetMarkerGoogleType(markerGoogleType[i]));
    marker.ToolTipText = clientTooltip[i];
    marker.Tag = i;
    marker.IsVisible = true;
    marker.ToolTipMode = MarkerTooltipMode.Always;

    GMapToolTip tooltip = new GMapToolTip(marker)
    {
        Offset = new Point(10, -10),
        Fill = ToolTipBackColor,
        Stroke = new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 0))),
        Foreground = foreground
    };

    marker.ToolTip = tooltip;

    markers.Markers.Add(marker);
}

gmap.Overlays.Add(markers);
```

Comment: You have to provide us the code which you have tried so far.

Comment: Please see my code below. Thank you so much.

Comment: I deleted the code below.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see your code Kalana

Comment: you have to accept my edit my friend. go to **recent inbox message** tab which is situated right-up coner. my edit will display for review.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24135415

Comment: I need to solve this problem. Haven't seen anyone support  :((

Comment: I am not good at tags that you have mentioned. I hope someone help you.best regards!

Comment: Yes, thanks for you support.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this GMap.NET library and it looks like there's barely any documentation on it so I can't say whether it supports custom map styles and can't help you with its implementation either sadly (hoping someone else will!).

However, in JavaScript, to hide POI icons on a JavaScript API map, you can add the following JSON (which you can get using the [Styling Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/)):

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

to your map's `styles` property. E.g.:

```
const mystyle = [
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  }
]

map.setOptions({styles: mystyle});
```

Hope this helps you find a similar C# GMap.NET solution.

Comment: Dear Pro, I know this in JavaScript. But I'm using C# :), I have searched a lot of places, but not found source code mention about this. Thanks for your reply.